# Make x-axis in vertical center using AChartEngine

Tags: android, android-view, achartengine

I am am going to make a app where i want to create a xy graph. AchartEngine API looks very attractive to me. I have seen all their examples and demos, Searched their forum but cant figure it out that if it can able to match my requirements.

So here is my question: 
I want a xy graph where:

1. Make the graph non scrollable. (Pending)
2. Make the x-axis vertically center as shown in image. (Pending)
3. Show labels only on x-axis. (Pending)

The Second Question is most important to me. Can some holly sole suggest me whether aChartengine do the required job.

http://s16.postimage.org/bqcewws4l/graph.png

Comment: Here are some patches to fix issue #2 http://stackoverflow.com/a/12176834/233048

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is possible with AChartEngine :)

Question #1:

```
renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
```

Question #2: You can control this by setting the yaxis min and max. They have to be such way chosen that 0 is in the middle. Example:

```
renderer.setYAxisMin(-10); 
renderer.setYAxisMax(10);
```

Question #3:

```
renderer.setYLabels(0);
```

Comment: Hi Dan Thanks for reply. My Question 1 and 3 are solved. But still looking for solution of #2. I have done what you say. I set the Ymin and Ymax values but the x Axis still in the bottom of screen. The origen of graph is now (0,-10) instead of (0,0). Please take a look at screen shot: http://s9.postimage.org/ky0ij8qov/image.png

Comment: Hi Gem , I am also facing same issue. Have you been able to solve this yet ? If yes please share . Thanks

Comment: for q3 you can rotate the text by an angle , it's somehow helping you even if its no your exact answer `multiRenderer.setXLabelsAngle(90);`