# Trouble getting axis centered on Origo in AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm having trouble getting AChartEngine to center the actual visible axises on Origo instead of having them along the left- and bottom of the chart.

I need to have the axises like so:

[image]

Any ideas?

(This question is similar to question #2 [2]: [Make x-axis in vertical center using AChartEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979790/make-x-axis-in-vertical-center-using-achartengine) but I thought that a more specific question might get an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some modifications to AChartEngine 1.0.0 to make it possible to display axises in the center of the plot.
Use code below to set the axises to center.

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.setXAxisAlign(Align.CENTER, 0);
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.CENTER, 0);
```

[XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.patch](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0YNo-RO7CbbNHEzWE45SUlrWVU%20) 
[XYChart.patch](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0YNo-RO7CbbSDVJeWFFNU9vMFk)

And here is an example on how it may look
[image]

Comment: Has this been fixed in recent release of achartengine ? Can i achieve this without modifying acharengine library

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a better answer than the one you mentioned. Just make sure that you calculate X and Y ranges such as your data fits inside and also make sure that the range you set is centered on the 0 point:

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(-value);
randerer.setXAxisMax(value);
```

and the same for the Y axis.

Comment: But that will not move the axis to the center, just make sure that the origo is in the middle of the plot.

Comment: The axis themselves cannot be moved to the center.