# How to patch achartengine?

Tags: java, android, achartengine, patch

I coded a small app and used the 'achartengine' libs. I'd like to add [two patches](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=392) because I'd like to have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156801/trouble-getting-axis-centered-on-origo-in-achartengine). But how do I do it?

Comment: Since aChartEngine is **open source**, you can do whatever patches you feel like.

Comment: You must be kidding me... download them as text files, there is written which file to modify, what to add or remove or change at which lines, ... once you downloaded the aChartEngine sources you can modify them freely.

Comment: Where can I find the aChartEngine sources (download)? I've only got the read-only

Comment: Confirmed that you are kidding me: What about right clicking on the extracted sources folder and removing the Read-Only attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [link](http://www.achartengine.org/content/demo.html)  Its easy if you understood the concept. Try to learn [AChartEngine](http://jandroiddevelopment.blogspot.in/2013/08/android-charts-using-chart-engine-part.html)