# How to build the achartengine library after modification?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, achartengine, libs

I modified the achartengine code to optimize it for myself but how do I build the lib in AndroidStudio? (I'm new in coding)

I found a build.xml file, so it should be possible to run `ant jar` to create the lib, but how do I do that...? or is there a better way?

Comment: AChartEngine is an open-source piece of code, written by somebody and offered to the community. Modifying it "for yourself" won't help it evolve. If the modifications you did are so brilliant maybe others could benefit from them?

Comment: These are [two patches](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=392) which are already available. I now want to build the jar-file again. Do you know how? please...

Comment: Please let me know which are the patches, I will take a look and if they look fine, I will add them to the code base and trigger a new build.

Comment: [Patches](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=392) from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156801/trouble-getting-axis-centered-on-origo-in-achartengine). But obviously they won't work :(

Comment: What do you mean by "obviously they won't work"?

Comment: Patched it but the methods as mentioned in [the first answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156801/trouble-getting-axis-centered-on-origo-in-achartengine) won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still interested in this (in 2019) ...

There are copies of achartengine on github, and the primary seems to be this:

- https://github.com/ddanny/achartengine

The project has both `build.xml` and `pom.xml` files, so it should be possible to build it with either Ant or Maven.   (I haven't tried though.)

There should be adequate instructions on how to use those tools in the Ant and Maven documentation.  And instructions on how to troubleshoot build problems.

I am guessing that the Dan D who commented above in 2014 is the Dan Dromereschi who owns the github repo.  (And I get the point he was making about not making private mods.  Open source depends on people being community minded and contributing to the project.  If you have worthwhile mods / patches, tell Dan about it.)