# How to make libs editable? Possible? (coding amateur)

Tags: android, android-studio, achartengine, patch, libs

I use the [achartengine libs](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) and downloaded the [achartengine-1.0.0.jar](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list) from google. I imported the library into my code and recognized that I can ONLY read it but I'd like to apply some patches. How can I make a library editable?

I use Android Studio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build the achartengine library after modification?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463308/how-to-build-the-achartengine-library-after-modification)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the jar-File are only the compiled `.class`-Files, no `.java`-Files.

If you want to edit or patch, you need the src-`.java`-Files. Here you can check out the SVN-Project:

https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/checkout

Here you can see the files, which you would need, if you want to edit the library:

https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fachartengine%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fachartengine%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the whole SVN-Project and then patch it, now I have to create a jar-File again but how?

Comment: Why you do not just put the source files into your project? Then you can patch whenever you want and you will not be forced to get the source files from that `.jar` again. Anyway if you want to create a jar: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: OMG You are a GENIUS. Thank You! You were the first person who helped me friendly. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Most Android Libraries have a pom.xml file which means that it should be built by maven. Install it, and navigate to the directory containing that file. Then `mvn install`. Reading the output, you will see where the artifacts(the jar) is stored.